# How to add up certain columns using awk in unix script

Tags: awk

I have to add up rows and choose columns. I want to use

File

```
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

with no arguments the script should return

```
6 (1st row)
3 (2nd row)
1 (3rd row)
```

Here's the code for this part that I made:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print(sum); sum=0 }' $FILE
```

with argument 1 and 2 (number of columns), the script should add every row in column 1 and 2 so it should return:

```
3 (1st+2nd column)
3 (1st+2nd column)
1 (1st+2nd (blank) column))
```

The only thing that I need is a condition to sum only certain rows

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variables to `awk` and you command would look like this:

```
awk -v col1=1 -v col2=2 '{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) {if (i == $col1 || i == $col2 ) sum+=$i}; print(sum); sum=0 }' $FILE
```

- `-v` `var=value`   assigns value to program variable var.

you can add as much columns as you want just add `-v colx=value`, then add ot to the condition `|| i == $colx`

If you want to pass the columns number to shell script, you can add them into an array let's say `columnsArray`, then create a variable `columns=$(echo "${columnsArray[@]}")`, then your command should look like this:

```
awk -v outCols="$columns" 'BEGIN{split(outCols, cols, " ")} { for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) {if (i in cols ) sum+=$i}; print(sum); sum=0 }' $FILE
```

for example

```
#!/bin/bash
columns=$(echo "$@")
awk -vcolss="$columns" 'BEGIN{split(colss, cols, " ")}{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) {if (i in cols ) sum+=$i}; print(sum); sum=0 }' test
```

would return:

```
3
3
1
```

Comment: And is there any way to pass certain columns I want to add? So when I make `./sum.sh file.txt 1 2` it will add first and 2nd columnd but `./sum.sh file.txt 1` will add only 1st column and `./sum.sh file.txt 2 3` will add 2nd and 3rd column and return `5 (1st row), 2 (2nd row), 0 (3rd row)`

Comment: something like this doesn't work: ` awk -v x="$1" '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (i == $x) sum+=$i}; print(sum); sum=0}' $PLIK` I'm waiting for you editing the post

Comment: Something like this doesn't work: `colmuns=$(echo "${tablica[@]}")
 
 awk -v columns="$columns" '{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) {if (i in columns ) sum+=$i}; print(sum); sum=0 }' $FILE` when I type ./sum.sh file.txt 1 2 there is an error

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I execute the script `./sum.sh file.txt 1 2 3` it returns the same as I would type `./sum.sh file.txt 1 2`.

Comment: Almost ok, `./sum.sh 1 2` returns 3 3 1 which is ok, but , `./sum.sh 2 3` returns the same thing whereas there should be 4 3 1

Comment: I've posted my answer. Anyway thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is answer I wanted to achieve:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PLIK=$1
    shift
    d=${@}
    awk -v c="$d" 'BEGIN {split(c,a," ")}{c=0; for(i in a) c+=$a[i]; print c}' $FILE
```

`./script.sh file.txt 1 2` will return `3 3 1` and `./file.sh file.txt 2 3` will return `5 2 0` which is correct